# Cannot find resource file in Resources folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

I've made a .wav file to play from application and added it to Resources folder via *Add > Existing Item*. However, when I try to do this:

```
soundPlayer.Stream = Properties.Resources.file;
```

It says that *ProjectName.Properties.Resources* doesn't contain definition for *file*. I've added file to right project and *soundPlayer* object exists.

Comment: Is it compiling, what is the compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the file.  Ex: myProject.Properties.Resources.fileName (the actual name you have given the file).

Here is more info about [adding and editing resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks bro, I have added it now via _Properties > Open > Resources > Add Resource (existing item)_ instead of _Resources > Add > Existing Item..._